# angular js $http.get returns object object

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to retrieve some sample values from mysql database and display it to my view using angularjs. I am pretty new to angular and I am trying to use $http.get to get my data. The following is my code

Angular Code

```
angular
.module('sampleApp.service.product', [])
```

.factory('productsService', [
'$http',
function ($http) {

```
        return {
            getProducts: function () {
              

             //   return $http.get("/Home/GetTweets");
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    
                    url: '/api/Products'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(data);
                }).error(function (error) {
                    //Showing error message 
                    alert("failed");
                    $scope.status = 'Unable to retrieve products' + error.message;
                });
```

alert(data) returns [object,Object]

My Controller code has the following

```
 public class productsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        ProductEntities context = new ProductEntities();
        var _products = from p in context.Products.AsEnumerable() select p;
        
        return _products;
    }
```

}

On debug I am getting the values in DB int the _products. Please help me out.Thanks In advance!

Comment: You can use `ngResource` module to interact with REST(-like) API. Here is a good article on how to use it. Take a look: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is successful as i can see

put `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data);` and then you can see the data in the browser console.

```
.factory('productsService', [ '$http','$q', function ($http,$q) {

    return {
        getProducts: function () {

             var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/Products'
            }).success(function (data) {

                deferred.resolve(data);

            }).error(function (error) {

                deferred.reject(data);

            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
     }
```

In the Conteroller,

```
productsService.getProducts().then(function(data) {
     //success
     $scope.products = data.rows; 
     console.log($scope.products);
}, function() {
     //flier
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Karlen..I will check it.@Kalhano..yes I am getting the data properly in console..however the place where i am calling the service the data is undefined. productsService
               .getProducts()
               .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                   $scope.products = data.rows;
                 //  alert(data.rows);
                   console.log($scope.products);
               });
               
             }

Comment: you have to use promises in this case. i updated my answer please check.

Comment: $scope.products has the value from db as its seen correctly in console. However its not getting displayed in my view. This is my code in view    ` <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
                    
                    
                    <td>{{product.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{product.Unit}}</td>
                  
               `

Comment: yeah great :) glad if u can upvote and mark as the correct answer if its solve ur issue :)